# Obtaining a single variable from a userform in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

I have little VB knowledge but was hoping to figure this out without any help, but *alas!*

I have a spread sheet that shows the layout of HP blades inside a chassis. Currently I have set-up a macro (I right-clicked view code on the sheet) whereby you click on a specific 'blade' (really a few merged cells) and an inputbox appears, asking the user which IP they'd like - this then looks for exact matches (e.g. O - OAM, I - iLO) and depending on the option selected - assigns a value in a case statement. For example: O - OAM IP would assign the number 2 - which performs a VLOOKUP and looks in column 2 to return an IP address to the users clipboard.

I'm trying to change the inputbox to a userform. I've created one and have a simple dropdown with the available options.

I'm struggling to export the users selection into a variable to be used later on.

All of my efforts so far result in a variable being assigned following completion of the 'userform' and pressing the 'OK' button. But that variable is then not assigned in the sheet's code area. I assume it's something to do with scope and assignment.

Code for the worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D57:H80")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim HostName As String
    Dim ColIndex As Integer
    Dim NodeIP As String
    HostName = ActiveCell.Value
    ufrmIPSelection.Show
    'uOption = InputBox("Option Required" & vbCrLf & "o = OAM IP" & vbCrLf & "i = iLO IP", "User selection required")
    'uOption
    MsgBox "Option captured is " & uOption
        Select Case uOption
            Case "OAM IP"
                ColIndex = 2
            Case "iLO IP"
                ColIndex = 3
        End Select
    MsgBox "Column referenced is " & ColIndex
    NodeIP = Application.VLookup(HostName, Sheet7.Range("A1:C503"), ColIndex, False)
    MsgBox "Hostname is " & HostName
    MsgBox "Node IP is " & NodeIP
End If
End Sub
```

and code for the userform OK button

```
Public Sub cmdOK_Click()
    uOption = cboIP.Value
    MsgBox "Combo Box Value " & uOption
    'Above line used to see if variable has been assigned
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: *I'm struggling to export the users selection into a variable to be used later on*. OK, I think you're on the right track re: scope. Can you show us the code from "later on" where you're trying to use the value from the `cboIP.Value`? Why not have the `cmdOK_Click()` button call the dependent procedure(s) and pass the value as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unload Me` essentially says "destroy this object". But a form's *default instance* isn't just any other object - it's a global instance that's automatically re-created by VBA whenever it's referenced again, if it's ever destroyed. But the re-created instance can't magically remember what the previous state was: the re-created instance therefore has whatever the inital / design-time state was.

Another thing that destroys a form and its state, is the little [X] button in the top-right corner.

A modal form is essentially a *dialog* - and a dialog can either be accepted, or cancelled. When the user dismisses your dialog by clicking that little [X] button, they're telling your program that they wish to cancel whatever that dialog was intended to be doing.

For this reason, it's important that a dialog does nothing other than *collect data* from the user. The basic code-behind boilerplate for a `UserForm` with an <kbd>Ok</kbd> and a <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button, might look like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private cancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = cancelled
End Property

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    OnCancel
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        OnCancel
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnCancel()
    cancelled = True
    Hide
End Sub
```

Handling the `QueryClose` event allows us to cancel the destruction of the form and the resetting of its state when the user clicks that [X] button.

Now the calling code can do this:

```
ufrmIPSelection.Show
If ufrmIPSelection.IsCancelled Then Exit Sub
```

But since that's storing the state in the form's global/default instance, it's a much better idea to do this:

```
With New ufrmIPSelection
    .Show
    If .IsCancelled Then Exit Sub
End With
```

That way every usage of the form is nicely insulated, and the form instance and its state only live as long as it *needs* to (i.e. it's gone at `End With`).

You could go ahead and query the individual controls' state from the calling code, but a much cleaner approach would be to *encapsulate* that state, using properties (a bit like suggested in [3.1415's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51405704/1188513)); these properties only need to be *read* from the calling code, so only a `Propery Get` member is needed:

```
Public Property Get SelectedIPType() As String
    SelectedIPType = cboIP.Value
End Property
```

And now the calling code can do this:

```
With New ufrmIPSelection
    .Show
    If .IsCancelled Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox .SelectedIPType
End With
```

The next step would be to extract an actual stateful class to encapsulate the *model*, so as to completely *decouple* the form from the data.

Read more about forms' default instance in [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/), an article I wrote a few months ago (the basic code-behind boilerplate snippet is taken from there).

Comment: This and 3.1415's answer have fixed my predicament! Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a [public property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/writing-a-property-procedure) to your form ...

```
Private m_OptionChoice as String

Property Let OptionChoice(value As String)
    m_OptionChoice = value
End Property

Property Get OptionChoice() As String
    OptionChoice = m_OptionChoice
End Property
```

And then change your OK button code to ...

```
Public Sub cmdOK_Click()
    OptionChoice = cboIP.Value
    MsgBox "Combo Box Value " & uOption
    'Above line used to see if variable has been assigned
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Now when your form closes, you can access the OptionChoice via `ufrmIPSelection.OptionChoice`. Eg change ...

```
MsgBox "Option captured is " & uOption
```

to ...

```
MsgBox "Option captured is " & ufrmIPSelection.OptionChoice
```

---

Finally, as suggested in Mathieu Guindon's comment below, you need to replace `Unload Me` with `Me.Hide`. Thanks Mathieu!

Comment: You're on the right track. But since the state is stored in the global/default instance of the form, that `Unload Me` basically resets the state to its initial default, making the calling code unable to retrieve the correct/intended state. Avoiding `Unload Me` and avoiding forms' default instance fixes this.

Comment: So, change `Unload Me` to `Me.Hide`?